# Insert R Data frame as parameter in SQL query WHERE clause

Tags: sql, r

Trying to insert R data frame as parameter in SQL query `where` clause but I get a SQL error.

This is my code:

```r
df <- data.frame(X=c(12691683,12693928)) %>% paste0(collapse = ",")

dbGetQuery(con2,"
  SELECT * FROM ORDERS WHERE ORDER_ID IN (", df, ")
")
```

Comment: You may want to consider parameterized queries vice constructing query strings manually. In addition to security concerns about *malicious* [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) (e.g., XKCD's [*Exploits of a Mom*](https://xkcd.com/327/) aka "Little Bobby Tables"), it is also a concern for malformed strings or Unicode-vs-ANSI mistakes, even if it's one data analyst running the query. `DBI` supports [parameterized queries](https://db.rstudio.com/best-practices/run-queries-safely/#parameterized-queries); `RODBC` does not (because `RODBCext` has since been removed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `glue::glue_sql()`, you could input multiple values for use in SQL `IN` statements by putting `*` at the end of the value and the values will be collapsed and quoted appropriately.

```r
df <- data.frame(X = c(12691683, 12693928))

glue::glue_sql(
  "SELECT * FROM ORDERS WHERE ORDER_ID IN ({df$X*})",
)

# <SQL> SELECT * FROM ORDERS WHERE ORDER_ID IN (12691683, 12693928)
```

In `base` you could also use `sprintf()` to create the SQL query:

```r
sprintf("SELECT * FROM ORDERS WHERE ORDER_ID IN (%s)",
        paste(df$X, collapse = ','))

# [1] "SELECT * FROM ORDERS WHERE ORDER_ID IN (12691683,12693928)"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use sprintf and toString.  No packages are used.  We assume this is an internal application where security issues are not relevant.

```
df <- data.frame(X=c(12691683,12693928))

sql <- sprintf("SELECT * FROM ORDERS WHERE ORDER_ID IN (%s)", toString(df$X))
sql
## [1] "SELECT * FROM ORDERS WHERE ORDER_ID IN (12691683, 12693928)"
```

A variation of  this is to use `with`

```
sql <- with(df, 
  sprintf("SELECT * FROM ORDERS WHERE ORDER_ID IN (%s)", toString(X)))
```

Comment: *"where security issues are not relevant"* should perhaps be bolded :-), but it's not always malicious: typos, unicode, different classes (strings, timestamps) all cause parsing problems when used in this fashion. The use of `sQuote` or similar is not a robust work-around. The only way to be agnostic to all of this variation is to use bound parameters (https://dbi.r-dbi.org/reference/dbbind and https://db.rstudio.com/best-practices/run-queries-safely/). It's not much extra work and it saves so much trouble down the road.

Comment: It should not be bolded because it is not relevant to 99% of R applications which are just add hoc statistical analyses.  I Just pointed it out since you always have somebody claiming it is a problem because of groupthink.  The example here does not involve quotes because the values are numeric.  If you do have character strings using quotes is not fragile and bringing in extra packages is not simpler and it does not cause problems down the road.

Comment: 1. No other packages, this is built in to `DBI`. 2. When somebody comes to this and applies your code to their problem, they may not understand when quotes are and are not needed. I know because there are still frequent questions that use this technique *here* without quotes (and don't work). 3. I understand that many R users are not deploying code to thousands of consumers, but shiny is easy, and that deployment can easily break on simple things. 4. This isn't groupthink, it's a "best practice" of SQL, even in R. My point though is not to debate, it's to add a comment to your answer.

Comment: The example in th e other answer used glue. That is an extra package.  The example in the question does NOT need quotes  It is completely irrelevant.

Comment: I wasn't making a comment about the use of `glue_sql`, though I find it much safer than `paste`, `sprintf`, and `toString`, if for no other reason than it properly quotes as required by the specific DBMS (not required with numbers, true). The reason I commented here was because of the mention of "security" as the only reason to worry about data binding: while that is the populous reason, it is not the only justification. I respect your work, even if we disagree on the value of the teaching moment here.